# refresh only if changed php-ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

well, I have a comment system that is updated every second with jQuery, but I want to update only if there are changes, that is, only if there are new records in the database. is there a way to do this?

Excuse my English, but I'm using google translator

Comment: you shoud read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) about long-polling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may create two function in JS. First function ask php script, which check changes, and, if data changed, run second JS function, which get data and update DOM.

Php is not may send info on loaded http page independently, without request from client side.